# Citrix .NET SDK GoToWebinar CreateWebinar C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, citrix

I am testing Citrix GoToWebinar SKD for .NET and for some reason one thing that doesn't work for me is new webinar creation. If anyone has any idea as to what I'm doing wrong please reply. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public CreatedWebinar CreateWebinarSingleSession(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, string subject, string description, bool isPasswordProtected)
    {
    var retVal = new CreatedWebinar();
    var webinarsApi = new WebinarsApi();

    var times = new List<DateTimeRange>();
    var timeFrame = new DateTimeRange()
    {
        startTime = startTime, // {30.6.2016. 14:16:03}
        endTime = endTime // {30.6.2016. 16:16:03}
    };

    times.Add(timeFrame);

    var newWebinarDetails = new WebinarReqCreate()
    {
        subject = subject, //"Webinar C#"
        description = description, //"Learn how to code in C#"
        isPasswordProtected = isPasswordProtected, //false
        //timeZone = "Europe/Warsaw",
        //type = "",
        times = times //{class DateTimeRange {startTime: 2016-06-30T12:16:03Z endTime: 2016-06-30T14:16:03Z}}
    };

    var newWebinar = webinarsApi.createWebinar(LoginResponse.access_token, Convert.ToInt64(LoginResponse.organizer_key), newWebinarDetails);
    if (newWebinar != null)
        retVal = newWebinar;

    return retVal;
}
```